# Designing a water tank factory process in LabVIEW

Tags: automation, labview, system-design, process-control

I am currently designing a factory process in LabVIEW. I have a tank filled with water. I want to transfer 80% from it to one tank and after that the remaining 20% into another tank. How can I do that in LabVIEW?

Comment: Your question is VERY broad. Try breaking this down into multiple separate steps/questions. But as a first step, I would suggest looking at the LabVIEW Example viewer for first guides. Help>Find Examples>Fundamentals, or Help>Find Examples>Control And Simulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabVIEW is a programming language. Design your application as you would in any other programming environment. I assume you have some sort of existing API for controlling a pump and for reading a depth sensor. Start the pump then run a while loop that polls your depth sensor. When the desired depth is reached, terminate the whole loop and then turn off the pump. If your sensor runs on an event system, use an event structure inside the while loop instead of the polling.